# SQL index out of range exception

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, indexoutofrangeexception

when I try to execute the SQL query shown below I get a IndexOutOfRangeException. I can't figure out why it is, on other SO pages it says that it could be because you try to get data from an non-existing field but I am certain that it exists and when i changed both of the requested fields from "ADRES" and "TAAL" to "LEV" like the one above them only the 2 bottom ones would refuse to work, while the top request for "LEV" still worked. "ADRES" is a 8 long varchar and "TAAL" is a 1 long varchar field

```
try
{
  //BESTEL,[PLAN],LEV,ADRES,TAAL
  SqlCommand getlist = new SqlCommand("select * from BESW where BEST=@best", Connectie.connMEVO);
  getlist.Parameters.Add("@best", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = data.corrigeerbestnr;
  DRorder = getlist.ExecuteReader();
  while (DRorder.Read())
  {
    dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DRorder["BESTEL"]);
    dateTimePicker2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DRorder["PLAN"]);
    comboBox1.Text = DRorder["LEV"].ToString();
    comboBox2.Text = DRorder["ADRES"].ToString();
    textBox8.Text = DRorder["TAAL"].ToString();
  }
}
catch (Exception er) { MessageBox.Show("" + er); }
```

EDIT: seems that if I split up the query like shown below it works, I really don't get why that is.

```
try
{
  //BESTEL,[PLAN],LEV,ADRES,TAAL
  SqlCommand getlist = new SqlCommand("select BESTEL,[PLAN],ADRES from BESW where BEST=@best", Connectie.connMEVO);
  getlist.Parameters.Add("@best", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = data.corrigeerbestnr;
  DRorder = getlist.ExecuteReader();
  while (DRorder.Read())
  {
    dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DRorder["BESTEL"]);
    dateTimePicker2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DRorder["PLAN"]);
    comboBox2.Text = DRorder["ADRES"].ToString();
  }
  SqlCommand getlist2 = new SqlCommand("select LEV from BESW where BEST=@best", Connectie.connMEVO);
  getlist2.Parameters.Add("@best", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = data.corrigeerbestnr;
  DRorder = getlist2.ExecuteReader();
  while (DRorder.Read())
  {
    comboBox1.Text = DRorder["LEV"].ToString();
  }
  SqlCommand getlist3 = new SqlCommand("select TAAL from BESW where BEST=@best", Connectie.connMEVO);
  getlist3.Parameters.Add("@best", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = data.corrigeerbestnr;
  DRorder = getlist3.ExecuteReader();
  while (DRorder.Read())
  {
    textBox8.Text = DRorder["TAAL"].ToString();
  }
}
catch (Exception er) { MessageBox.Show("" + er); }
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? On which line you get this error?

Comment: Which line throws the exception?  What is the index being used on that line?  What are the indexes available on that object at runtime?

Comment: @David combobox1 works fine but as soon as it gets to combobox2 it gives the error, when i changed the order so combobox2 was last of the query i noticed textbox8 also gave that error. if i put those 2 as comment the query will work fine, also i tried to set the field that they use both to "LEV" since that one worked for combobox1 but it still gave the error on  just those 2

Comment: @maam27: In your debugger, inspect the runtime value of `DRorder`.  What fields does it have?  No matter how sure you *think* you are about what fields should be there, you need to debug to find out.

Comment: @David the moment the code gets to combobox2 it goes to the catch with the error and it should have that field for the query requests all fields of that table, if this isnt what you were asking for then i dont quite understand what your question is, so if you would explain it a bit more to me so i could give that what you asked me about

Comment: @maam27: If the error is telling you that the field `"ADRES"` doesn't exist, then it doesn't exist.  No matter how sure you think you are, the runtime isn't lying to you.  An `IndexOutOfRangeException` means that index isn't there.  You can inspect the `DRorder` object at runtime in your debugger to see what *is* there.  But nobody here can do that for you.

Comment: _the moment the code gets to combobox2 it goes to the catch with the error_ That clearly indicates that the fileds is not there resp. has a different name. Check the spelling!

Comment: ill add a screenshot of the database rows im trying to request in that query, as it they fields do exist and the spelling is right.

Comment: @maam27: Is the exception coming from the database object?  Or from the combo box object?  Split that line into two lines (one to get the value from the data, the next to set it on the combo box) to test.  The point is, you need to *debug* this.  You can argue with the code all you want, but it's not going to change its mind.  You're continuing to *refuse* to actually inspect the runtime values, and instead you're simply trying to convince us that it *should* work.  Even if you convince us, that's not going to fix the error.

Comment: @David im not trying to convince you i just don't know where the error is and some say the field is non existing so im just showing that it is there and that unfortunately that isnt the cause, if it was i would have been able to resolve it. i tried it and when the line was split it still couldn't set it to the string either

Comment: @maam27: No, you haven't shown us that the field is there.  You've shown us that you *believe* the field *should be* there.  But in your debugger you have *not* examined the fields that actually *are* there.  When you step through the code in the debugger, you can examine the actual runtime value of `DRorder`.  That will show you what *is* there.  Not what you *believe should be* there.

Comment: @David it seems that when i set every other line to comment and i only try to recieve the "TAAL" or "ADRES" it works fine without a error, so now i really don't get why it gives that error anymore. EDIT: if i put 2-3 of those lines together in the query it breaks but they work individual, i tried putting each of them in a seperate query and they just work.

Comment: Your table does not seem to contain "PLAN" judging from the print screens. Unless you removed it from your query, then its just confusing.

Comment: @NickOtten "PLAN" is in the db and isn't causing any issue so i removed it from the query and only shown a few columns since there are quite a few. however i can understand what you are saying, but i also found a way that the query works atm and posted that as a awnser here however its only a work around.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It apears that when I split the fields into seperate queries they just work, the queries are not altered it just doesn't have all the rows in 1 query. I still don't really know why it did that but using seperate queries at least works around that issue.

Comment: I dont know why someone would downvote my comment on my own question... im just posting this as a workaround since I haven't gotten/found a real solution yet, if there is one submitted on this post I will just set that one as awnser. But I dont think my awnser would be useless on my question.

Comment: This answer doesn't really describe the solution presented and is of little use to anybody who may be trying to solve the same problem.  "split the fields into separate queries" and "doesn't have all the rows in 1 query" are very vague statements and don't add any meaningful solution information.  You're basically saying, "I managed to work around the issue."  That's great that you found a workaround for your own needs, but this answer serves no purpose in explaining that.

Comment: i know that it might not help others with the issue and im not saying this is a final thing but im just posting this as to say that it did work for me, if i find a solution it will be posted ofc

Answer (score 1):

There could be two possible errors
1. The any of the column could be missing or misspelled.
2. You are trying to set the property to a combo box, which might not have the queried data as its item.

Hope it helps.

**Edit:** Say, combo box has two items "Yes" and "No", you could be trying to set "Neither of them" as its current item.

Comment: Im just trying to set the data from the database as the text of the combobox like when a user would have typed something in there, and it wouldn't explain why the textbox is giving the same error

Comment: @maan27: The text you set in the combo box has to be in the list of values of that combo box. Else its out of range (as your exception indicates).

Comment: May be you could test it by using two text boxes behalf combo boxes to confirm if that is the issue...

Comment: but if a user types in it it doesnt matter if its in the list or not and i tried to split up the line of code to go to a variable first like @David suggested and it couldn't set it to the variable either. so its not a issue with the combobox or so it would seem to me at least